# how to use Axios to upload image in binary data in react native?

Tags: react-native, axios, postman

I am using Axios for API calls. I want to upload an image from mobile to the server. API is accepting data in binary form image. It is working fine from POSTMAN. But I cannot understand how to pass images in Axios in code.

This is the API curl from Postman.

```
curl --location --request PATCH 'https://{baseURL}/v1/device/image' \
--header 'accept: application/json' \
--header 'Content-Type: image/jpeg' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic MTIwODU4MTM3MTk6Z2tNUWpRVWM=' \
--data '@'
```

[Postman sample api calling.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OiBf.png)

```
  try {
  
      // Make the API request
      await request({
        url: 'device/image',
        data: imageData[0].base64, // here what I need to pass exactly.
        method: 'PATCH',
        config: {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg',
            accept: 'application/json',
            maxContentLength: 100000000,
          },
          maxBodyLength: Infinity,
          maxContentLength: Infinity,
          responseType: 'json',
        },
      })
        .then(async (res: ApiResponse<any>) => {
          console.log('res ::: ', res.data);
          // Handle the response as needed
        })
        .catch((e: any) => {
          console.error('Oops :: ', e);
          // Handle the error as needed
          toast.show({
            type: 'error',
            message: e.message || 'Something went wrong',
            position: 'top',
          });
        });
    } catch (error) {
      console.warn('error ::: ', error);
      // Respond with a 500 Internal Server Error if something goes wrong
      return;
    }
```

this is the file data I get.

```
{"fileName": "1854487B-07A2-4BFA-9B64-B047202F8877.jpg", "fileSize": 2567402, "height": 2848, "type": "image/jpg", "uri": "file:///Users/theonetech/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/FEC6EBCC-8A7E-4D43-B5E7-F5EB9F512EBF/data/Containers/Data/Application/A2FFD8E2-C3EE-45B0-A811-5467E27A761E/tmp/1854487B-07A2-4BFA-9B64-B047202F8877.jpg", "width": 4288}
```

I found one resource on the internet. https://medium.com/@j.lilian/how-to-use-axios-to-send-binary-data-579c3334ba72

But not able to understand.

Comment: What is `request` in your code?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The example assumes you have the binary image data or can obtain it. If you are working with an image picked from the device, you can use a library like react-native-image-picker to get the image data. Adjust the code accordingly based on your specific use case.

You can use 'react-native-image-crop-picker' to pick image and video. Set following property to true

includeBase64: true

and image file content will be available as a base64-encoded string in the data property

```
ImagePicker.openPicker({
  mediaType: "photo",
  includeBase64: true // this will give 'data' in response 
})
.then((response) => {
    console.log(response.data)
})
.catch((error) => {
   alert(error)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

```js
import { Buffer } from "buffer";
import { readFile } from "react-native-fs";

// other code.

  const updateUserData = async () => {
    if (profileImage) {
      let path = profileImage.uri;
      path = profileImage.uri.replace("file:", "");
      await readFile(path, "base64")
        .then(async (contents: any) => {
          const body = Buffer.from(contents, "base64");
          await request({
            url: "device/image",
            data: body,
            method: "PATCH",
            config: {
              headers: {
                "Content-Type": "image/jpeg",
              },
            },
          })
            .then(async (res: ApiResponse<any>) => {
              console.log("res ::: ", res.data);
              // Handle the response as needed
              login(res.data);
            })
            .catch((e: any) => {
              console.error("Oops :: ", e);
              // Handle the error as needed
              toast.show({
                type: "error",
                message: e.message || "Something went wrong",
                position: "top",
              });
            });
        })
        .catch((error: any) => console.log({ error }));
    }
}
```